# Can anyone explain this reference with Jeremy Piven?

Tags: plot-explanation, unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt, jeremy-piven

In *Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt*'s Episode 2 we see a large box of DVDs with Jeremy Piven on the cover playing the drums with the title 'Own the Skins' being dumped in a box marked 'FREE':

[image]

Can anyone explain the reference here? This looks like a fictional DVD as I couldn't find it on Amazon.

I see that [he can actually play the drums](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jeremy%20piven%20drums%20with%20the%20roots&rlz=1C1SVEF_enGB436GB436&oq=jeremy%20piven%20drummer&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l2.7896j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=jeremy%20piven%20drums).

So is this just a tease?

Comment: It's just a joke. 30 Rock had similar ones too, just random things that never had any real meaning but were just jokes. [As Entertainment Weekly says](http://www.ew.com/recap/unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt-season-2-premiere/2): `In the world of Kimmy Schmidt, The Salvation Army is “The Salvation Coast Guard” and Entourage and Mr. Selfridge star Jeremy Piven has made a drum instructional DVD called “Own The Skins.”`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a joke. *30 Rock* had similar ones too, just random things that never had any real meaning but were just jokes.

[As *Entertainment Weekly* says](http://www.ew.com/recap/unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt-season-2-premiere/2):

> In the world of Kimmy Schmidt, The Salvation Army is “The Salvation
>   Coast Guard” and *Entourage* and *Mr. Selfridge* star Jeremy Piven has
>   made a drum instructional DVD called “Own The Skins.”